# PrestaShop: Delete all testing data before production

Tags: prestashop

I'm searching a script to run on MySql to delete (truncate table)  all the testing data (customer, order,cart, etc) on a PrestaShop database version 1.4.9.
Thank 
Pascal

Answer (score 12):

Install the Prestashop Cleaner and in configure you have options to delete catalog, orders and customers

Comment: Looks like the best answer so far. `PrestaShop Cleaner` is a free module available in the repository and it does exactly the task in a couple of clicks.

Comment: For those who needs step by step guide I found this http://www.psfever.com/2014/delete-sampledemo-data-prestashop/

Comment: New name of PrestaShop Cleaner is "PS Cleaner"

Comment: In PS 1.6 it's also called `Database Cleaner`. Just search for `cleaner`.

Answer (score 2):

For 1.5.6.2 (probably works for 1.5.6*, even maybe for 1.5.*) :

```
TRUNCATE `ps_access`;
TRUNCATE `ps_address`;
TRUNCATE `ps_alias`;
TRUNCATE `ps_attribute`;
TRUNCATE `ps_attribute_group`;
TRUNCATE `ps_attribute_group_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_attribute_group_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_attribute_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_attribute_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_carrier`;
TRUNCATE `ps_carrier_group`;
TRUNCATE `ps_carrier_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_carrier_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_carrier_tax_rules_group_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_carrier_zone`;
TRUNCATE `ps_cart`;
TRUNCATE `ps_cart_product`;
TRUNCATE `ps_category`;
TRUNCATE `ps_category_group`;
TRUNCATE `ps_category_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_category_product`;
TRUNCATE `ps_category_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_cms`;
TRUNCATE `ps_cms_block`;
TRUNCATE `ps_cms_block_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_cms_block_page`;
TRUNCATE `ps_cms_block_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_cms_category`;
TRUNCATE `ps_cms_category_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_cms_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_cms_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_connections`;
TRUNCATE `ps_contact_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_contact_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_customer`;
TRUNCATE `ps_customer_group`;
TRUNCATE `ps_delivery`;
TRUNCATE `ps_feature`;
TRUNCATE `ps_feature_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_feature_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_feature_value`;
TRUNCATE `ps_feature_value_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_guest`;
TRUNCATE `ps_homeslider`;
TRUNCATE `ps_homeslider_slides`;
TRUNCATE `ps_homeslider_slides_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_image`;
TRUNCATE `ps_image_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_image_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_image_type`;
TRUNCATE `ps_manufacturer`;
TRUNCATE `ps_manufacturer_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_manufacturer_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_orders`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_carrier`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_cart_rule`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_detail`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_detail_tax`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_history`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_invoice`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_invoice_payment`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_invoice_tax`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_message`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_message_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_return_state`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_return_state_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_state`;
TRUNCATE `ps_order_state_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_page`;
TRUNCATE `ps_page_type`;
TRUNCATE `ps_product`;
TRUNCATE `ps_product_attribute`;
TRUNCATE `ps_product_attribute_combination`;
TRUNCATE `ps_product_attribute_image`;
TRUNCATE `ps_product_attribute_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_product_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_product_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_product_supplier`;
TRUNCATE `ps_product_tag`;
TRUNCATE `ps_range_price`;
TRUNCATE `ps_range_weight`;
TRUNCATE `ps_reinsurance`;
TRUNCATE `ps_reinsurance_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_scene`;
TRUNCATE `ps_scene_category`;
TRUNCATE `ps_scene_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_scene_products`;
TRUNCATE `ps_scene_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_search_index`;
TRUNCATE `ps_search_word`;
TRUNCATE `ps_specific_price`;
TRUNCATE `ps_stock_available`;
TRUNCATE `ps_stock_mvt_reason`;
TRUNCATE `ps_stock_mvt_reason_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_store`;
TRUNCATE `ps_store_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_supplier`;
TRUNCATE `ps_supplier_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_supplier_shop`;
TRUNCATE `ps_supply_order_state`;
TRUNCATE `ps_supply_order_state_lang`;
TRUNCATE `ps_tag`;
```

Will give you a clean, ready database before you start.

Comment: helped, I just removed ps_contact_lang and ps_contact_shop as it's more a config parameter (to my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly note, that this site not for finding scripts for any kind of your work. It is just to give advices and based on that advices give step by step guidance and sample scripts / codes . 
How you can remove the test data from your PS installation is easy.

1) Go to Admin panel.
2) Delete categories and products
3) Delete customers
4) Delete carts and orders.

This is the easiest way. But if you want to truncate the tables for them, then follow the following steps

1) Go to PhpMyAdmin at your server.
2) Find the database your PS installation is using
3) For customers, truncate ps_customers, ps_address
4) For cart, truncate ps_cart, ps_cart_products
5) For orders, truncate ps_order, ps_order_details,

Please note that the above truncation will only remove those data from the admin and also from the database, but there are some other tables also which can be truncated. But necessarily required, because if you dont do that, then the data will be not shown at admin, so no need at all. I cant list them, because with new PS versions, tables are changed.