# prestashop 1.6 admin reset

Tags: admin, reset, prestashop-1.6

First time user. Installed Prestashop 1.6 last night locally on my computer (I want to try it out before I commit to it). However when I got to the admin panel it had the same presets as found in the demo version (http://www.prestashop.com/en/demo).

So, figuring I may have just somehow, accidentally downloaded the demo version, I uninstalled and reinstalled just a few minutes ago. Yet, lo and behold, I get the same presets. Is there anyway to do a reset on the admin panel so that I get a clean slate (no orders, customers, stats, etc)?

Downloaded Prestashop from the homepage. Used this article (blog.dh42.com/installing-prestashop-locally/) to download it locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your solution : http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/320579-delete-all-sample-data/

1. Go to your back office
2. Modules
3. Search for `cleaner`
4. Install `pscleaner` module

Use this module.

Another solution here : [PrestaShop: Delete all testing data before production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277017/prestashop-delete-all-testing-data-before-production)